# Chamar o compilador Java a partir de uma classe Java

Tags: java

Então, é o seguinte, gostaria de saber se tem como eu chamar o compilador Java a partir de uma classe em execução, para compilar outra e gerar o .class dela.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer executar o comando javac pra compilar seu .java programaticamente?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [JavaCC](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc1.6). Não sei se é isso exatamente o que você quer.

Answer (score 3):

Use o método [`ToolProvider#getSystemJavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler--) para obter uma instância de [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Então você pode compilar classes usando o modelo abaixo (extraído da documentação):

```
File[] fontes = ... ;
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits1 = 
    fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(fontes));
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();
fileManager.close();
```

Existem vários outros pontos da API para explorar e posso dizer que em geral não vale muito a pena mexer com isso a não ser que você esteja construindo uma IDE ou um novo compilador para uma linguagem dinâmica.

Para a massiva maioria das tarefas cotidianas de compilação você deve preferir uma ferramenta de gerenciamento do ciclo de vida do projeto como Gradle, Maven, SBT ou até mesmo Ant.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que você tem JDK na sua máquina e que ela é Windows, podes fazer algo do tipo:

```
 Process process = new ProcessBuilder("%JAVA_HOME%\\bin\\javac.exe","<caminho para o fonte>").start();
```

Pra um contexto mais geral você pode fazer também dessa maneira, que já "puxa" o ambiente que tá sendo usado pra executar a aplicação atual:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac <caminho para o fonte>");
```

Comment: Não tem jeito de fazer isto de uma forma melhor em Java? Só em gambi?

Comment: @bigown Uma solução feia e uma decente.

Comment: Onde está a decente? :)

Comment: @bigown Note que eu não disse que era boa. Só é decente, faz o que ele quer "em qualquer plataforma". Ele ainda vai ter que fazer alguma lógica pra puxar o local do arquivo, mas como isso não foi especificado fica só a parte crucial do negócio.